# Как сделать компактным однотипный код?

Tags: delphi, инспекция-кода

Сделала вот такой рабочий код.

При запуске программы, проверяется, наличие папки **Direct** и 8 файлов, что в этой папке (FL1.txt - FL8.txt). Папка создается возле самой программы.

С точки зрения компактности и правильности - написания кода: **Можно сделать код покороче или код сделан нормально ?**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
const
  Fn = 'Direct\FL1.txt';
  Fn2 = 'Direct\FL2.txt';
  Fn3 = 'Direct\FL3.txt';
  Fn4 = 'Direct\FL4.txt';
  Fn5 = 'Direct\FL5.txt';
  Fn6 = 'Direct\FL6.txt';
  Fn7 = 'Direct\FL7.txt';
  Fn8 = 'Direct\FL8.txt';
var
  F, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8: TextFile;
  FName, FName2, FName3, FName4, FName5, FName6, FName7, FName8: String;
begin
  FName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Direct';
  if ForceDirectories(FName) then
  else
    ShowMessage('Не удалось создать структуру папок.');

  // Файл в той же папке, где расположен исполняемый файл программы.
  FName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + Fn;
  FName2 := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + Fn2;
  FName3 := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + Fn3;
  FName4 := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + Fn4;
  FName5 := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + Fn5;
  FName6 := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + Fn6;
  FName7 := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + Fn7;
  FName8 := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + Fn8;

  AssignFile(F, FName);
  AssignFile(F2, FName2);
  AssignFile(F3, FName3);
  AssignFile(F4, FName4);
  AssignFile(F5, FName5);
  AssignFile(F6, FName6);
  AssignFile(F7, FName7);
  AssignFile(F8, FName8);

  // Если файл существует, то открываем его для записи данных.
  // Иначе (если файл не существует) - создаём файл и открываем его для записи.
  if FileExists(FName) then
    Append(F)
  else
    Rewrite(F);
  CloseFile(F);

  if FileExists(FName2) then
    Append(F2)
  else
    Rewrite(F2);
  CloseFile(F2);

  if FileExists(FName3) then
    Append(F3)
  else
    Rewrite(F3);
  CloseFile(F3);

  if FileExists(FName4) then
    Append(F4)
  else
    Rewrite(F4);
  CloseFile(F4);

  if FileExists(FName5) then
    Append(F5)
  else
    Rewrite(F5);
  CloseFile(F5);

  if FileExists(FName6) then
    Append(F6)
  else
    Rewrite(F6);
  CloseFile(F6);

  if FileExists(FName7) then
    Append(F7)
  else
    Rewrite(F7);
  CloseFile(F7);

  if FileExists(FName8) then
    Append(F8)
  else
    Rewrite(F8);
  CloseFile(F8);
end;
```

Comment: Вы умеете работать с массивами?

Comment: @Kromster, Пытаюсь освоить и знаю что делаю ошибки, но потому и спрашиваю. Еще год назад я даже не знала что такое Delphi, вообще.

Comment: @Татьяна переходи сразу на C# и WinForms! имхо там все интересней

Comment: @dgzargo переходи сразу на Delphi и FMX! имхо там все интересней

Comment: @dgzargo, Совет то хороший, но мне кажется, нужно, хотя бы, что то одно выучить. Насколько я знаю, то есть читала, C# сложнее будет для начинающих. А вот переход с Delphi на C# возможен, только в том случае, если есть хороший уровень знаний. А мой уровень знаний очень слабый в Delphi. Но я стараюсь изо всех сил. В будущем буду смотреть. А сейчас, это, очень сложная задача, по крайней мере - для меня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var 
  files: array[1..8] of TextFile;
  names: array[1..8] of string;
  i: integer;
begin
  // make sure folder exists
  ForceDirectories(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Direct');

  for i := 1 to 8 do
  begin
    names[i] := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Direct\FL' + IntToStr(i) + '.txt';
    AssignFile(files[i], names[i]);
    if FileExists(names[i]) then
      Append(files[i])
    else
      Rewrite(files[i]);
  end;

  ...

  for i := 1 to 8 do
  begin
    CloseFile(files[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Еще один момент по вашему коду. Когда сами файлы в папке удаляю то при запуске программа их создает все нормально. А вот когда саму папку то ничего не создает. То есть не проверяет папку - на создана или нет.

Comment: Благодарна Вам Igor за дополнение. Теперь, код, стал, в разы короче и удобней. Обязательно ознакомлюсь, более подробней, с информацией по работе с массивами.

Comment: можно также в первый цикл closefile перенести. А вообще код должен быть не компактным, а читабельным. Лучше каждое логическое действие в процедуру размещать.  Типа процедуры PrepareDir, ProcessData, WritedataToFile.

Comment: @AlbertFomin Я предположил, что файлы все же для чего открывают, а не чтобы сразу закрыть.